# Jquery Mobile and HERE maps api

Tags: jquery

I am using a JQuery Mobile App and try to implement a HERE-map but the problem is, the map dosn't appear when I am putting it into the JQuery-mobile -Container within my `<body>`

If i am planting the map outside the JQuery-mobile container it works...

Is there someone facing the same problem or having a solution for this issue?

```
<!-- HERE MAPS -->
<div id="mapContainer" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></div>
```

Comment: Maybe this has something to do with the stylesheet of JQuery-Mobile?

Comment: you should try to emulate a mobile device on a browser and see what happens on the style

Comment: I've also tried to run it on the browser, same result :/

Comment: I've also tried now to implement it with google maps, its workin within the jquery container....strange problem, because google maps is doin exactly the same thing